my hp pavilion notebook with 2GB NVidia GeForce GTX 930M not detecting any USB plugin
my system is hp pavilion notebook having 2GB NVidia GeForce GTX 930M.
it not detecting any USB flash drive and any USB plugins like mouse, keyboard etc.
I have tried almost all USB troubleshooting techniques like
-restarting
-uninstalling the driver
-windows update
-disabling power save option
and all methods at this https://www.makeuseof.com/usb-device-not-recognized-error-windows/
the following is my device manager detail.
my device manager detail

Suggest booting it from a live Linux CD and see if any USB peripherals are recognised. That will distinguish Windows driver failures from hardware fault. Also try Safe mode. It has been a while since I had that sort of fault and it was very specific with one USB 2.0 port refusing to see a very particular USB keyboard. Junk accumulates in the registry... Nothing doing anywhere at all sounds like it could be bad news.

I restarted my computer in save mode and restarted live linux CD. nothing happen. still all USB not working
